# remove element from DOM with slideUp animation

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I want to remove element from data in the controller, and that should remove node-element from DOM with slideUp animation.

I tried in controller:

```
$scope.remove = function (i) { $scope.items.splice(i, 1); };
```

My [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dATLDJnKHMMNclaV7Mao?p=preview) with attempt to use ngAnimate

But it works totally wrong.

Is it any adequate method to remove HTML element from DOM with animation by removing item from array via `$scope.items.splice(i, 1);` ??!?!

This is backbone implementation:

```
initialize: function () {
    var that = this;
    collection.on('destroy', function (model) {
        that.$('.items[data-id="' + model.id + '"]').stop().slideUp();
    });
},
remove: function (e) {
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var id = el.data('id');
    collection.get(id).destroy()
},
```

Here is totally wrong ngAnimate in my plkr:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that the animation is not working here is not because of your method to remove the HTML element but rather due to the tracking behavior for ng-repeat.

This [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvO5tXrobSRZujd4q4GT?p=preview) is a modified version of what you had provided. I have removed the 'track by $index' and binded $index to be displayed for each list item as follows:

```
<li class="slide" ng-repeat="item in things">{{$index}} {{item}}<a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefaul(); removeThing($index)">Remove thing</a></li>
```

If you focus only on the $index value that I have added to each list item, removing an item will appear as if the last item is always being removed. Hence, this seems to be the reason that you kept seeing the last thing being removed when using 'track by $index'.

Note here that I just use the default tracking behavior but because ng-repeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays, it will not work in scenarios where what you are trying to add already exists. If you look at the API reference for ng-repeat found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), there seems to be good examples on other ways you can use 'track by'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it works not a properly. please, check my screenshot. https://yadi.sk/i/UnQm3gzZgX868

Comment: @JohnSmitt Sorry might not be understanding what you exactly want. Can you elaborate on your screenshot?

Comment: dear @JBang I think that duplicated items are wrong. on the screenshot you can see two "3 item". do you think that it's ok?

Comment: @JohnSmitt I'm assuming that number value here is the $index? The modified plunker was just intended for you to have a better picture of 'track by $index' behavior. Do you need the numbering on the rows to shift up? If not you can probably create your own index like this  [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4UEYeeauiYlUNcV0lxFk?p=preview)

Comment: awesome, thanks! could you please add the last your plnkr into your answer?